# jQuery carousel is not smoothly scrolling

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am trying to create a carousel in jQuery that is constantly scrolling much like a stock ticker (ie: there should never be a pause in the scrolling animation.)

See a jsFiddle example of what I have attempted so far here: http://jsfiddle.net/c5VQe/

Using the following code, I've created a carousel in 3 lines of code that does exactly what I want except that there is a slight delay after the carousel rotates one time.

```
function RotateCarousel() {  
    $("ul li:first-child").animate({ marginLeft: -200  }, 1500, function () {
        $("ul li:first-child").appendTo('ul');
        $("ul li:last-child").css('margin-Left', 0);
        RotateCarousel();
    });
}
```

How can I get rid of this delay?

Note: I'm not interested in using any plugins.  It should be possible to eliminate the delay without resorting to a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: If I'm interpreting your question correctly, look for the `easing` attribute in the `.animate()` documentation, and set it to `linear`.

Comment: Awesome implementation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `easing` option to `linear`:

```
$("ul li:first-child").animate({ marginLeft: -200 }, 1500, 'linear', function () {
//                                                         ^-- here
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/c5VQe/4/)

As you haven't set one before, jQuery defaults it to `swing`.

From the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) docs:

> ### *Easing*
>
> The remaining parameter of `.animate()` is a string naming an easing
>   function to use. An easing function specifies the speed at which the
>   animation progresses at different points within the animation. The
>   only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default,
>   called `swing`, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called
>   `linear`.

---

Side-note: Your `setTimeout()`'s syntax was wrong, it should be

```
setTimeout(RotateCarousel, 1500); //passing a function object reference
```

To delay the init of the carousel.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I knew that a simple solution had to exist.